# Is it possible to change Firebase domain to custom domain without Firebase Hosting?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-hosting

I have a fully-built web app that uses Firebase auth and database. It's hosted on Netlify.

I want my users to see my custom domain when authenticating with Google, here:

[image]

Is it possible to do this without hosting my app files on Firebase Hosting?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify **where** your users would see anything related to Firebase Hosting when signing in to Firebase Authentication? There are a few places that I can think of, but as far as I know they should all be configurable to any domain, not just domains hosted on Firebase.

Comment: I added an image to clarify my question @Frank Van Puffelen

Comment: Thanks for the update. I think you're looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44815580/how-to-replace-the-myapp-123-firebaseapp-com-with-my-custom-domain-myapp-com or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47532134/changing-the-domain-shown-by-google-account-chooser or some other results from https://www.google.com/search?q=firebase+authentication+change+firebaseapp.com+domain+in+account+picker

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking about customized email handlers (verification email, password reset emails etc) then yes, you can generate links pointing to any site, put there your custom handlers and from their implementation call appropriate firebase API to complete the process.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Alex. I added an image for clarification.